# Jetpack Compose cant compile the app, could not find kotlin-compiler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Lately I have been strugling trying to make jetpack compose run... I have follow all the example codes, downloaded canary and all, but the 1.4.0 plugin is not working for me and I get compile problems

These are my gradle files

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
    ext.compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha01'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha08"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion kotlin_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion compose_version
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

    //Fundamental building blocks of Compose's programming model and state management, and core runtime for the Compose Compiler Plugin to target.
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"

    //Fundamental components of compose UI needed to interact with the device, including layout, drawing, and input.
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"

    //Build Jetpack Compose UIs with ready to use Material Design Components. This is the higher level entry point of Compose, designed to provide components that match those described at www.material.io.
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"

    //Write Jetpack Compose applications with ready to use building blocks and extend foundation to build your own design system pieces.
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"

    //Build animations in their Jetpack Compose applications to enrich the user experience.
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"

    //In charge of annotators like @Preview and tooling for render views
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

The error I get is this one

```
Could not resolve compiler classpath. Check if Kotlin Gradle plugin repository is configured in project ':app'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.0.0-alpha01/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.0.0-alpha01/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.0.0-alpha01.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.0.0-alpha01/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.0.0-alpha01/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I have tried with this version, I have followed the documentation, the jet news example and everything but I cant compile the project, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have missmatched the compileOptions

```
 composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion kotlin_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion compose_version
    }
```

should be

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
```

Comment: I didn't have the same problem, but this options are fixing another error. I spent lots of time to find it out. In this case, I'm leaving here the error message, so people would have opportunity to fix the problem.
Error message:
`e: This version (1.0.0-beta07) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.32 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.31 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or 'suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck' but don't say I didn't warn you!).`

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin to see whether your `composeOptions` `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` property - in your app gradle file - is compatible with your kotlin version.